# Execute substring

Tags: 7, database

I want to execute a "SELECT " and the conditions use the " substring " postgres

e.g:" SELECT * from desembolso_cnu WHERE substring(fecemi_pub,1,4)='2016'"

How could I do with the use of **db_select**

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 there is a `substring_index` method that gets created on install with PostgreSQL. This can be used when using the `where` method on a select query object.

```
$query = db_select('desembolso_cnu');
$query->fields('desembolso_cnu');
$query->where('substring_index(fecemi_pub,1,4) = :year', array(':year' => '2016'));
```